# Ignore Blank Cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am having difficulty having this macro copy and paste only the cells that have data in them. I would like the macro to only select and copy the cells in the columns that have data, ignore the empty cells. what I currently have is this

```
Sub testest()

Sheet4.Activate

'Dim lrow As Long
'lrow = Sheet4.Range("A", Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheet4.Range("A2:A40").Select

Selection.Copy
    Sheet5.Activate
Sheet5.Range("A2").PasteSpecial

Sheet4.Activate

Sheet4.Range("B2:B40").Select
Selection.Copy
    Sheet5.Activate
Sheet5.Range("B2").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to paste only the cells with data by shifting the other cells up to fill in the blank ones, you should try the following commands after you select your desired copy range:

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

This logic mirrors going to "Find and Select" > "Blanks" > "Delete"

Comment: **For the sake of VBA - don't use `Select` or `Selection`.** Plus I don't think that the OP wants to delete anything - the question was how to copy only cells that are filled.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, merely a way to show you how to reduce your code, by eliminating the obsolete activation and selection actions:

```
Sub testest()

Sheet4.Range("A2:A40").Copy
Sheet5.Range("A2").PasteSpecial

Sheet4.Range("B2:B40").Copy
Sheet5.Range("B2").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

In fact, why don't you simply do this:

```
Sheet4.Range("A2:B40").Copy
Sheet5.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
```

(Ranges can go over different columns)

There are ways to avoid the usage of the clipboard, but then the complexity of the macro increases, which, I believe, is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer by @Dominique, but addressing the empty cells and assuming you gave up on the last row method:

```
Sub testest()
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Sheet4.Range("A", Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Sheet4.Range("A2:A" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheet5.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
    
    Sheet4.Range("B2:B" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheet5.Range("B2").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```